# How to avoid OOM to load large images from android resource

Tags: android, resources, out-of-memory

I have developed 20+ android apps, apps have a tutorial activity that are composed of large image slide (ex; 4 images in the size of 750 x 1334) and would be shown to users at the first launch.

I cannot reduce the sizes anymore, because of image quality.

My code snippet is following;

```
public class GalleryImageActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener {
ViewPager imagePager;
GalleryImageAdapter galleryImageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_image);

    imagePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);

    galleryImageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this);
    imagePager.setAdapter(galleryImageAdapter);
    imagePager.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
}


public class GalleryImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public static int SCREEN_CNT = 4;
Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[SCREEN_CNT];

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return SCREEN_CNT;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_image_item, null);
    ImageView imv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    bmp[position] = readBitMap(context, R.drawable.tutorial_img_0 + position, position); 
    if (bmp[position] != null)
        imv.setImageBitmap(bmp[position]);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    if (bmp[position] != null && !bmp[position].isRecycled())
    {
        bmp[position].recycle();   
        System.gc();  
        bmp[position] = null;
    }
}

public Bitmap readBitMap(Context context, int resId, int position) { 
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, opt);
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    opt.inPurgeable = true;
    opt.inInputShareable = true;
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, opt);      

    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }            

    return bitmap;
}
}
```

sometimes it works well, but when repeat 5~6 times, BitmapFactory.decodeStream throws "Out of memory".
How can i decide scale size or resolve this problem?

the example images are following;
[image]

Comment: I am using Picasso if you want to use third party lib. for me Picasso is working

Comment: When you say you repeat 5-6 times what do you mean? what are you repeating?

Comment: @Nitish thanks, i like use [nostra13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nostra13.universalimageloader/universal-image-loader/1.9.3) as third party lib. PageAdapter will not destroyItem soon, so 2~3 images were loaded at the same time.

Comment: @tyczj after launched app, tutorial activity also can be run from about app menu. i click about app menu, then see and close tutorial activity, i repeated this case 5~6 times.

Comment: I would be willing to bet you either are not completely clearing your bitmap array or your image views are not getting garbage collected, When your activity (or page) gets destroyed I would also set the imageview's bitmap to null so it no longer has a reference to a bitmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify `readBitMap` function as the following;

```
public Bitmap readBitMap(Context context, int resId, int position){ 
    if (bmp[position] == null || bmp[position].isRecycled())
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 

        opt.inPurgeable = true;  
        opt.inInputShareable = true;        

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        opt.inScaled = true;
        opt.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT; // !important

        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);  
        try {               
            bmp[position] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,opt);
        } catch (Exception e){
            bmp[position] = null;
        }           
    }

    return bmp[position];
}
```

Some type of mobile phone, especially SAMSUNG, is not well-designed about memory leak.

**`opt.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT`**  is very important.

If `inDensity` is `0`, `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` will fill in the density associated with the resource. [more...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inDensity)

And you should set the imageview's bitmap to `null`, when your activity (or page) gets destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

A bitmap of size 750x1334 in `RGB_565` config requires around 2MB memory. 3 of them can be stored in 6 MB, which should not create `OutOfMemoryError` if handled with care.

Here are some tips that you can follow.

- Use `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag of your manifest.
- Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for your `ViewPager`.
- Don't forget to recycle bitmaps as soon as they are no longer needed.
- Use `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();` after you recycle your bitmaps.
- If you are storing images in `drawable`, move them to `drawable-nodpi`.
- Use Glide or Picasso library.

Answer (score 1):

Try using some image loading library like Picasso or Glide. That will simplify things a lot.

But in your case, I think the issue is not in decoding the image, but rather you are holding on the bitmap already created in memory. Ensure that you only have one Bitmap in memory at all times. Just open your Profiler in studio, and confirm if you are not storing references to multiple bitmaps.

Comment: even if i added the code in destroyItem, problems are exists. that is adapter,,adapter will  be load 2 pages at least.

Comment: I too had this type of issue once. The problem was, I created multiple bitmaps, but some of them had references and was not destroyed. I used the Profiler to confirm the Memory. The Memory view will help you out in this. Just run your and then each time a Bitmap is decoded, the Memory will spike. If there are no references to your Bitmap, tapping on the GC icon should reduce the spike back to normal. If not, then you have a problem.